# add record to a file in java

Tags: javascript, json

guys i am using jqgrid .. here is my file

```js
{ 
 "rows":[
  {"OrderID":"10248","FromDate":"1996-07-04","CustomerID":"WILMK","ShipName":"Vins et alcools Chevalier","ToDate":"1996-07-05"},
  {"OrderID":"10249","FromDate":"1996-07-05","CustomerID":"TRADH","ShipName":"Toms Spezialit\u00e4ten","ToDate":"1996-07-17"},
  {"OrderID":"10250","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"HANAR","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes","ToDate":"1996-07-26"},
  {"OrderID":"10251","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"VICTE","ShipName":"Victuailles en stock","ToDate":"1996-08-01"},
  {"OrderID":"10277","FromDate":"1996-08-09","CustomerID":"MORGK","ShipName":"Morgenstern Gesundkost","ToDate":"1996-08-12"}
 ]
}
```

but i want it to be like

```js
{ 
 "rows":[
  {"OrderID":"10248","FromDate":"1996-07-04","CustomerID":"WILMK","ShipName":"Vins et alcools Chevalier","ToDate":"1996-07-05"},
  {"OrderID":"10249","FromDate":"1996-07-05","CustomerID":"TRADH","ShipName":"Toms Spezialit\u00e4ten","ToDate":"1996-07-17"},
  {"OrderID":"10250","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"HANAR","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes","ToDate":"1996-07-26"},
  {"OrderID":"10251","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"VICTE","ShipName":"Victuailles en stock","ToDate":"1996-08-01"},
  {"OrderID":"10277","FromDate":"1996-08-09","CustomerID":"MORGK","ShipName":"Morgenstern Gesundkost","ToDate":"1996-08-12"},
        {"OrderID":"10261","FromDate":"1996-07-19","CustomerID":"QUEDE","ShipName":"Que Del\u00edcia","ToDate":"1996-08-09"} // added row
 ]
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between these two ?? only number of spaces at the last line I think.

Comment: please add what you have tried so far. okk.

Comment: the last row in the second file is the added data from add row button .. so what i want is to pick these data and add them in the last row in the file

Comment: Are you using Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like, you want to add another object in json file within an array. So, here is a solution.

- Read your json file with whatever library you are using to read/write json from files.
- Add the new object in the specific list.
- Write that to file with over write mode.

Answer (score 0):

First parse your JSON content:

```
String input = "{\"rows\":[{\"OrderID\":\"10248\"}]}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(input);
```

Then get the array from the parsed content:

```
JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("rows");
```

Convert the object to add to JSON:

```
JSONObject newRow  = new JSONObject();
newRow.accumulate("OrderID", 10000);
// Do the same for all your attributes
```

And finally add the new row to the array to get your updated JSON:

```
arr.put(newRow);
String updatedJSON = json.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to add another object in `json` file within an array. So, here is a solution.

1. Read your `json` file.
2. Put your key `row` as a `JSONArray` and Store it into a String.
3. Construct a Class `Order`.

   ```
    Class Order
    {
    String OrderID ;
    String FromDate ;
    String CustomerID 
    String ShipName;
    String ToDate;
   }
   ```

Add the new object in the specific list.

```
//import Class (add a jar com.fasterxml.jackson to your project)
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


// Here I assume that "applicationArray" contains the Array .
 String applicationArray = "[
        {"OrderID":"10248","FromDate":"1996-07-04","CustomerID":"WILMK","ShipName":"Vins et alcools Chevalier","ToDate":"1996-07-05"},
        {"OrderID":"10249","FromDate":"1996-07-05","CustomerID":"TRADH","ShipName":"Toms Spezialit\u00e4ten","ToDate":"1996-07-17"},
        {"OrderID":"10250","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"HANAR","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes","ToDate":"1996-07-26"},
        {"OrderID":"10251","FromDate":"1996-07-08","CustomerID":"VICTE","ShipName":"Victuailles en stock","ToDate":"1996-08-01"},
        {"OrderID":"10277","FromDate":"1996-08-09","CustomerID":"MORGK","ShipName":"Morgenstern Gesundkost","ToDate":"1996-08-12"},
        {"OrderID":"10261","FromDate":"1996-07-19","CustomerID":"QUEDE","ShipName":"Que Del\u00edcia","ToDate":"1996-08-09"} // added row
    ]"

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Order> obj_listOrder = mapper.readValue(applicationArray, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, DeviceApplication.class));
```

Now add one more element to the list .

Add One More element to the List.
Replace the content of Your file.